# How do I know what files to include in order to manually copy my WPF executable to another machine?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I'm re-doing an old .NET 2.0 app in WPF4 and C#. I don't have the ability to to use an installer with this app. With the old version, all I had to do was copy a single .exe file. But with the WPF app I see I need more than that. But how much more? I can copy the DLL's over one at a time till it runs, but I don't feel safe doing it this way. So how can I know what folders (I see several language folders) and files I truly need?

My end goal is to only need to still use a single executable file. I will either add the needed DLL files as embedded resources, or use ILMerge. The smaller number of files I need to do this with the better.

PS. I can't use an installer as a condition of my employer. My app is meant as a tool to assist our techs on support calls. The fact that it uses .NET was met with resistance so I'll comply with the rules.

Thanks

Comment: Get the ability to use an installer with the app. Or use ClickOnce. They are both designed to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't use an installer. I have to copy the file in manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from dependencies on the machine itself (.net framework 4 for example) you'll only need what's in the project's output folder, by default bin/Debug.

Comment: That's not true. What about thirdy party controls or assembly installed in GAC and with CopyLocal=False?

Comment: Don't you mean bin/Release? Don't want to deploy debug build.

Comment: There are quite a bit more files in the WPF version than the WinForms version. I'm looking to weed out only the files I absolutely need since I plan to ultimately embed those files in the final assembly.

Comment: @Steve that's what I meant by dependencies